# Can any(some) generator(s) of adjoint representation of SU(3) (Gell-Mann construction) be reducible under SU(2)?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

I was going through another thread on MathStack which was dealing with a specific question from Georgi, Lie Algebras in Particle Physics. I am not specifically looking for an answer/clarification with regards to Particle Physics. Also, the thread came off as somewhat abstract and in the accepted answer I happened to chance across terms which were unexplained. I am putting the question here again. I have answered the first chunk of the question apart from the adjoint part. I haven't seen any resource explain reducibility under a sub-representation.

> Show that $T_1$ , $T_2$ and $T_3$ generate an SU(2) subalgebra of
>   SU(3). Every representation of SU(3) must also be a representation of
>   the subalgebra. However, the irreducible representations of SU(3) are
>   not necessarily irreducible under the subalgebra. How does the the
>   representation generated by the Gell-Mann matrices transform under
>   this subalgebra. That is, reduce, if necessary, the three dimensional
>   representation into representations which are irreducible under the
>   subalgebra and state which irreducible representations appear in the
>   reduction. Then answer the same question for the adjoint
>   representation of SU(3).

I am unable to comprehend as to how to address the adjoint part in depth. I have been seeing quite a lot of hand waving arguments as to how the reduction may be done, but I guess I am having difficulty understanding how to show it either through brute force adjoint representation, or by using adjoint generator transformations.

Now, say, I have the three adjoint representation generators of SU(3),constructed by hand, which I did, how do I show that they are a Kronecker product of two irreducible representations of lower dimensions, under SU(2)

Comment: When you write $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$ do you in fact mean the Lie algebras?

Comment: Hi, yes. I do mean the respective SU(n) Lie Algebras.

Answer (score 1):

Probably of no use to OP at this point but for anyone who might stumble in here like I did, you can "brute force" the problem by putting the adjoint $T_1$, $T_2$, and $T_3$ into block diagonal form with a similarity transformation. Take

$S = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}-i & 0 & -i &  &  &  &  &  \\ 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0& & & & &  \\ -1 & 0 & 1 & & & & &  \\  & & & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & \\ & & & -i & 0 & 0& -i & \\ & & & 0 & i & -i & 0 & \\ & & & 1 & 0 & 0& -1 & \\ & & & & & & & \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$

to see how they break down into $SU(2)$ irreducible representations (it's not a product of two by the way, but a direct sum of four). As for the method to derive something like this on your own, I don't have a great answer. I can list the steps I went through though.

1. Pick one to diagonalize (I chose $T_2$)
2. Take inventory from its eigenvalues to get an idea of what representations you can make from them
3. Make a similarity matrix from the normalized eigenvectors
4. Trial &  error with the phase factors of each vector until a representation from your inventory appears in the block diagonal